# UNITY - AVPRO - GUI not work

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-mediaplayer, virtual-reality

I'm an absolute novice on Unity an I have a lil problem on my mediaPlayer VR app.

My Intro is not working properly.
None of my GUI event works: Here's 1 of my Log errors.

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   VRStandardAssets.Utils.SelectionSlider.OnEnable () (at Assets/VRSampleScenes/Scripts/Utils/SelectionSlider.cs:45)

And here's the code pointed by this error:

```c#
private void OnEnable ()
    {
        m_VRInput.OnDown += HandleDown;
        m_VRInput.OnUp += HandleUp;

        m_InteractiveItem.OnOver += HandleOver;
        m_InteractiveItem.OnOut += HandleOut;
    }
```

Thx a lot.

Comment: Which is the line 45? And where do `m_VRInput` and `m_InteractiveItem` come from?

Comment: They're from my `public event Action OnBarFilled`

`[SerializeField] private VRInput m_VRInput;`
`[SerializeField] private VRInteractiveItem m_InteractiveItem;`
I have this problem everytime I use them events. 
the line 45 is `m_VRInput.OnDown += HandleDown;`

Comment: Then is either `m_VRInput` not set within Unity at the moment the function is called or `HandleDown`.

Comment: So do you know how to fix it? i'll continue searching inside unity and i keep in touch